# System.OutofMemory Exception excel 1 GB data

Tags: c#, excel

I have 2 excel files in Server with size of 1GB each.
I have to compare the files and should send the results in a separate table.

I was able to read one excel file into a data table and when I am about to read the data for another excel, I am getting out of memory exception.

```
file = new FileInfo(@"Remote Location" + strFileName);
bool hasHeader = true;

file.CopyTo(strPath, true);
file = null;
using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
{
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(strPath))
    {
        pck.Load(stream);   //Getting issue out of memory for second excel file
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Off-topic, but one should not call `Dispose()` if you are going to use `using()` blocks.  Just use the latter

Comment: Actually I added it before using.. I removed displose and close..but still getting same exception.The datatable is need for comparison..So if I discard it,i might loose the data.

Comment: Do you need to compare spreadsheet structure or their data?

Comment: I need to compare the data in the 2 excel sheets

Answer (score 4):

You are at the limit of what a 32 bit process can handle. Make sure you are using 64-bit Windows and make sure you are running your app in 64 bit mode, right click Project->Properties->Build and force it to x64 from the typical default of "Any CPU".

There may be a better solution to your problem though, why not treat each Excel sheet as a data source using the [Excel ODBC driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255)? My thoughts are it would be far more efficient.